# ограничить вывод символов

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток всем, постал такой вопрос как огранить вывод символов из БД средствами php
делаю таким образом

```
mb_substr('<p><span style="font-size:14px">текст какой то <span></p>',0,60,'UTF-8');
```

этот код считает и теги html, как сделать что бы считало только ТЕКСТ?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, мне кажется, здесь регулярки - то что доктор прописал. Текст из тега можно взять таким способом: `<([a-z0-9]+)[^>]*class="clean"[^>]*>(.*?)(<\/\\1>)`. Если нужно ТОЛЬКО текст(даже из вложенных тегов), то поменяйте (.?*) на `[a-z(что хотите еще)]*?` или `[^<>]*?`

Comment: омг [strip_tags](https://php.net/strip_tags)

Comment: Да, в данном случае это проще. Но часто нужно решить попутные задачи, типа вырезать что-то из тега, тогда регулярки с их карманами очень помогают.

Answer (score 0):

профильтруй функцией htmlentities

Comment: так тупо выводится <p><span style="font-size:14px">текст какой то <span></p> строка

Comment: `strip_tags()` же

Comment: тоже не работает